# How to edit a gem and then use that version in your Sinatra app on Heroku

Tags: path, heroku, sinatra, paperclip, gemfile

I am attempting to load an edited version of the dm-paperclip gem in a Sinatra app being deployed on Heroku. I downloaded the edited gem here https://github.com/ladicha/dm-paperclip/commit/8ff8d235edf03c7c21c49c0103c5b013d543d406.

In my Gemfile I added a :path argument for dm-paperclip

```
gem 'dm-paperclip', :path => "#{Dir.pwd}/gems/ladicha-dm-paperclip-8ff8d23"
```

When I push to Heroku the bundler runs with no errors. Concerning the dm-paperclip gem heroku's bundler reports

```
Using dm-paperclip (2.4.1) from source at gems/ladicha-dm-paperclip-8ff8d23
```

The app is then deployed, but crashes. I believe the relevant line in the log is

```
 <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- dm-paperclip (LoadError)
```

I am pointing :path to the location of 'dm-paperclip.gemspec' which I believe is correct. Anyone see what I am doing wrong? If you need more info I'd be glad to supply it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm dodging the question here of using :path gems on heroku, but does this work for you?

```
gem 'dm-paperclip', :git => 'https://github.com/ladicha/dm-paperclip.git'
```

As for why it doesn't work, I'd definitely be wary of using `Dir.pwd` in a Gemfile. `File.dirname(__FILE__)` might be a workable alternative, but it still feels dirtier than the git option.

Comment: No you aren't dodging the question and I agree that using the git method is better. This has been a learning process and I realized later that the "right" way to do it was to link to the git fork directly. Alass, I still had the app crash with the same error. Not sure what the deal is. I worked around it by switching to the bamboo stack which runs ruby 1.8.7 like I have been using in development. Heroku and dm-paperclip seem to be behaving together now. I think the ultimate solution is to ditch dm-datamapper as it hasn't been touched in 2 years. Thanks Matt!

Comment: Do you think my whole problem is that I developed the app in Ruby 1.8.7 and was pushing to a stack on Heroku which is running 1.9.2?

Comment: @three I will probably switch to carrierwave.

Comment: @wuliwong, no, don't think the difference between 1.8 and 1.9 matters in that case.

Comment: It's actually possible it's a 1.8/1.9 difference. 1.9 doesn't include "." in the load path anymore. If the code in dm-paperclip assumes that it is, that may be the source of the error.